# Trouble with MultiMap reading in data?

Tags: c++

So the objective of this is to read in a text file that contains a number and a name which looks like this:

```
50 Leonardo
20 Donatello 
100 Rapheal
40 Michelagelo
```

I was just at the point of printing it out to check it had gone in right. Instead of getting a duplicate of the text file as I expected I get the last name repeated for all the names.

This is what I get:

```
Michelagelo 50
Michelagelo 20
Michelagelo 100
Michelagelo 100
```

The code:

```
ifstream top;   
    char output[100];
    char* defaultName = "Default";
    int tempTop;
    char* tempName;


    top.open("top.txt");        
    top.clear();
    top.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::beg );


    typedef multimap <char*, int> MM;
    MM top;

    if (top.is_open()) {        
        while (!top.eof()){

            //Get Score
            top>>output;
            tempTop=atoi(output); 


            //Get Name
            top>>output;
            tempName=output;

         cout << "Writing: " << tempName << " and " << tempTop << endl;
         top.insert(MM::value_type(tempName,tempTop));

        }
    }       

    MM::iterator i;

     for(i=top.begin(); i!=top.end(); i++){
          cout << (*i).first << " " <<  (*i).second << endl;
     }
     cout << "Size is: " << top.size() << endl;
```

My other question was that I am using this multimap as I was lead to believe it would result in a sorted list?

Quite confused and would appreciate the error of my newbie ways being shown to me.

TIA

Comment: Char-pointers are not the same as strings. Use `std::multimap<std::string, int>`.

Comment: A multi-map is for having multiple values at the same key. Your example input does not require that and your example code is treating the map like a `std::vector`. A sorted list would be a `std::set` usually. What container do you really want?

Comment: @AJG85 it will probably have entries that are duplicates eventually.

Comment: @EricBanderhide Just throwing out options. The first task is to identify which container best suits your needs then we can address the use of `char*` instead of `std::string`, having two variables named `top` in the same scope, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems stem primarily from attempting to use `char *` directly, instead of using `std::string` like you should. If you insist on using `char*`, you'll need to dynamically allocate each string you use, and provide a comparator object to compare the contents of the strings instead of the pointers.

Bottom line: use `std::string` unless you have no other choice. If you truly *can't* use `std::string`, you almost certainly want to write a class of your own that provides at least roughly similar capabilities (though probably without a lot of the searching, replacing, etc.)

When you're finished with that, you're going to have another minor problem: `while (!top.eof())` is pretty much guaranteed to lead to problems (typically seeming to read the last line of the file twice). You almost certainly want to read the values and base continuation of the loop on the result of the attempted read.

```
while (top >> number >> name)
    MM.insert(MM::value_type(number, name));
```

Edit: If I were doing this, I'd probably implement it just a little differently, to avoid writing an explicit loop at all. I'd start with something like:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, int> v_t;

std::istream &operator>>(std::itream &is, v_t &v) {
     is >> v.second;
     std::getline(is, v.first);
     return is;
}
```

That should read the data from one line of the input file. Then you can use an `istream_iterator` to populate your multimap:

```
std::ifstream top("top.txt");

// define multimap, initialized from stream:    
std::multimap<std::string, int> MM((std::istream_iterator<v_t>(top)),
                                    std::istream_iterator<v_t>());
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I don't know why I used char* to being with. 

Could you explain the last bit some more, if I change my code to mirror yours it only reads the first 2 lines of the file.

Comment: @EricBanderhide: Not sure why you'd only get first two lines (unless the data wasn't right), but I've edited some slightly different code into the answer anyway, that reflects how I'd normally approach the problem (where the first was really only a minimal change to fix an obvious problem).

Answer (score 1):

When you insert into a multimap, you're inserting a copy of the type that you used for the template parameter. In this case it's a `char *`. Making a copy of the pointer *does not* make a copy of the string! The next time you insert you're inserting the same pointer, so now you have two pointers to the same string. As that string gets overwritten with the new input, all the copies in your map change.